# js fancybox без кнопок

Tags: javascript, fancybox

При вызове функции `$.fancybox.open(this);` помимо preloader-а  инициализируются   кнопки http://joxi.ru/VrwykjwtKkekX2, как запустить preloader без них, или как это сделать правильно?  fancybox v.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.fancybox.open(this,{modal : true});`